# Movement of the Sun in space

Tags: the-sun, black-hole, galaxy, milky-way

Does the Sun undergo any cycles or revolutions approximately every 24,000 years or 8.6 million years? In Hinduism it is believed that the Sun revolves in an elliptical orbit around a large mass at these rates.

Comment: I assume you are referencing the 24 [divine millennia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Among_the_Devas) of the [Vishnu Purana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Purana), which, under the equation 1 divine day = 1 human year, yield somewhere between 8.6 and 8.8 million human years; see [Hans Kung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Kung), *[Tracing the Way](http://books.google.com/books?id=sm0BfUKwct0C&pg=PA50)*.

Answer (score 3):

The [precession of the Earth's spin axis orientation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession) takes place on a 25,700 year cycle. But this isn't connected with the Sun's movement through space.

The Sun orbits the Galaxy about once every 220-240 million years. It also oscillates about the Galactic plane with a period of about 70 million years.

Answer (score 1):

The sun revolves around the galactic centre and completes one revolution in approximately 250 million years. The Sun's orbit is around 25,000 light years away from the galactic centre.

Other than these, it doesn't have any cycles or movement corresponding to the numbers you specified.